# What will happen if the $z$-component of quantum angular momentum is zero?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, angular-momentum

If $l,m=0$ that is $L_z |0\rangle = 0|0\rangle$ and $L^2|0\rangle = 0|0\rangle$, But

$$L^2 = (L_x)^2 + (L_y)^2 + (L_z)^2$$

$$(L_x)^2 |0\rangle = -(L_y)^2|0\rangle  $$

Does this mean that I measure $Lx^2$ and $L_y^2$ simultaneously when I am measuring  it in $|0\rangle$ which is an eigenstate of $Lz$?

Is uncertainty principle not violated by this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the total angular momentum is zero, you can conclude that the individual components of angular momentum are all zero, so there can't be any uncertainty.

In this particular case, the uncertainty principle states that

$$\sigma_{L_x} \sigma_{L_y} \geq \left|\frac{1}{2i}\langle[L_x, L_y]\rangle\right| = \frac{\hbar}{2}\left|\langle L_z\rangle\right| = 0$$

so there is no violation.

Comment: Try to use $\langle$ (\langle) and $\rangle$ (\rangle) instead of $<$ and $>$.

Comment: Yeah right, thanks